# MySql NOT IN Performance problem

Tags: mysql

I am running the query below on a table with around 100k rows in it using a NOT IN and the performance is terrible. Is there another way of achieving the same result?

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.address, c.town,
c.county, c.postcode, FROM contractor AS c
inner join Order w
on w.Id = c.Id WHERE (c.valid = 1) and c.Id not in
(select w.Id from Order w) ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: This query should not return any rows. Your join only gets c.Id's that are equal to w.Id's (and therefore are IN select w.Id from Order w). Furthermore, there's a syntax error (the ',' after c.postcode).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a redundant inner join to `Order`.
I believe following query would yield the same results and might improve performance.

```
SELECT  c.Id
        , c.Name
        , c.address
        , c.town
        , c.county
        , c.postcode
FROM    contractor AS c 
        left outer join Order w on w.Id = c.Id 
WHERE   (c.valid = 1) 
        and w.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
        c.Name ASC
```

Comment: I think this is what the TS wanted, +1.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it is still running as i speak (2-3 minutes)... Is there a way to use a NOT EXISTS?

Comment: It's probably slow because you haven't indexed your columns. Put an index on the c.Id and w.Id column and you should be good to go.

Comment: As Lex said, you probably need to index you columns. You should take a look at the query plan for confirmation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally can't see further improvement to your code except that you might want to add indexing to your fields. The general rule is to add index to the columns you use in your `WHERE` clause.